# Splitting a PDF each time the page number resets to 1

Tags: python, pdf

In Python, I'm wondering if I can split one PDF file into several each time the page number in the PDF document is reset to 1.  There is no pattern for how many pages before the page number is reset.  For example, I have a document with pages numbered as:

```
1 2 3 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 1 2
```

I’d like to have 5 documents:

```
1:  1 2 3
2:  1 2
3:  1 2 3
4:  1 2 3 4 5
5:  1 2
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using to read / parse your PDF files?

It would help to match an answer to your specific use case

Comment: Are these page numbers _true_ pages numbers or just text representing numbers? I mean, in the process of pdf-creation did you use some particular flags/tags? In the "worst" case an OCR approach is always possible

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using PyPDF2 for Python 2.7.18.  Once I figured out how to use it, it was pretty easy.  The 2.7.18 version was totally revamped in preparation for going to Python 3.  However, they have a wrapper to allow you to use the older syntax.  Don't use it!  Just use the newer syntax, because the wrapper has a bug in it.  We were using Word to convert documents to PDF.  Unfortunately Word does not store page numbers as labels, so I ended up having to parse the document, which PyPDF2 allows you to do.  Given I knew where the page number was, I was able to extract the page number.  Every time the page number reset to 1, I output a new document.